# symfony2 doctrine mongodb - how to check a field in document is updated

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony, doctrine

In `doctrine mongodb` of `symfony2`, is there a way to catch an even `postUpdate` or `onFlush` or `preUpdate` to check if a field in a document is updated? Example that I have is a document `Post` which has fields: `Id, name, description`. I have a `Listener service` to catch the event when `Post` is updated.

```
<?php

namespace Acme\Bundle\PostBundle\Listener;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\DocumentManager;
use Doctrine\ODM\MongoDB\Event\LifecycleEventArgs;

public function postUpdate(LifecycleEventArgs $eventArgs)
    {
        /* @var $odm DocumentManager */
        $odm = $eventArgs->getDocumentManager();
        $object = $eventArgs->getDocument();

        if ($object instanceOf Post) {
          // how to check if description field is updated
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During `preUpdate` you can check document's change set:

```
public function preUpdate(PreUpdateEventArgs $e)
{
    $e->getDocumentChangeSet();
    $e->hasChangedField('description')
}
```

Changeset is associative tuple which looks like

```
[ 'description' => [ 'old value', 'new value' ] ]
```

For more available methods you can check out [`PreUpdateEventArgs`](https://github.com/doctrine/mongodb-odm/blob/c1e9777d1e083d819a354553522903b3b83a6f39/lib/Doctrine/ODM/MongoDB/Event/PreUpdateEventArgs.php) class

Comment: But when I use Sonata admin. I have a field: `status` and it's a `choice` field form. When I'm  `preUpdate` the `post` document, event if I'm not change the field `status`, it's still go to the condition `if($e->hasChangedField('status')`

Comment: That warrants debugging on your side, generally if value is the same it won't be included in change set nor in the update query that ODM is issuing later